# How to convert a compressed sound file to uncompressed file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, core-audio

I want to uncompress a compressed sound file in my iPhone/ipad app.
In my app , I have .m4a files which I wanted to convert to .wav form.
How is this possible through code?

Comment: Do you mean convert the _format_? Once something's been compressed, you can't increase the quality/resolution of the sampled sound.

Comment: Yes, actually I want to know the waveform of the compressed file

Answer (score -1):

You can use ExtAudioFile to do this:

```
CFURLRef url = /* ... */;
ExtAudioFileRef eaf;
OSStatus err = ExtAudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)url, &eaf);
if(noErr != err)
  /* handle error */

AudioStreamBasicDescription format;
format.mSampleRate = 44100;
format.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
format.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFormatFlagIsPacked;
format.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
format.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
format.mBytesPerFrame = format.mChannelsPerFrame * 2;
format.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
format.mBytesPerPacket = format.mFramesPerPacket * format.mBytesPerFrame;

err = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(eaf, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(format), &format);

/* Read the file contents */
```

Obviously I just arbitrarily chose 16-bit integer stereo as the format to retrieve, but hopefully the idea is clear.  You just tell ExtAudioFile what format you would like your audio data in, and it automatically converts from the file's format to your requested (client) format.

Apple has more extensive sample code at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ConvertFile/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: When I try your exact code above (after fixing the stutter in the format flags) I get a "fmt?" error.  Any idea what the problem could be?